# Dynamic mic windscreen shape

Tags: microphone

Does the shape of a handheld dynamic microphone's windscreen (i.e. a rounded top vs a flat top) have any effect on the sound, or is it just for aesthetics?

Comment: What is the Microphone Windshield with the flat top Called? I can't find them anywhere. Please Someone Respond :)

Comment: @LachlanReid - you might have better luck if you try asking a new question about this.  I'd also suggest you ask about what reasons would be to use one over the other to make it a question more interesting to those who might know the answer.

Comment: it has an effect on the wind screening effectiveness, but not on the sound being recorded

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aesthetics... and yes...

I could probably drum up some intelligent sounding reason for having one shape over another, but the shape is not going to determine the performance of the windscreen.

If something did change it's performance, it would be material, density, thickness.  At least one of those aspects could be altered by shape I suppose.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is just aesthetics; the sound of a handheld dynamic microphone’s windscreen does not depend on the shape. It is just an accessory. The sound depends on the distance to the mic.

Comment: What is the sound of a microphone's windscreen?  Just an accessory?  Do they have no effect then?  In your last sentence, I assume "sound" refers to the recorded sound?; if so, distance of what to the mic, the windscreen? the audio source?  Your answer raises many questions :)